# Xcode14 run normal Xcode 15: Undefined symbols: Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode

upon upgrading to Xcode 15, my widget extension is causing this error:

`ld: Undefined symbols:   _main, referenced from:       <initial-undefines> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

When pressing the error, nothing happens. It doesn't show me which symbols are undefined.
How should I fix this?

try adding -ld_classic to the linker options,but it don't work

Comment: Seems it does not see the «_main». Try to add a new extension to create a new project with a widget extension to see if there has been some changes in build settings that may not have been reflected to your project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was missing `@main` annotation on `AppDelegate` which is entry point for the app.

So the resulting code was:

```swift
import shared

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        // ...
        
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is apple DTS engineer answerd me

Your project isn’t linking because it has the Mach-O Type build setting overridden to a blank value. When looking at your app’s build settings, select the item at the project level, rather than at the target level, and search for Mach-O. You’ll see a green highlight on this setting, showing that it is set, which happens to be a blank value. Select the Mach-O row and press the delete key, and the green highlight will disappear, as the setting will be unset. Your share extension was inheriting this blank value, so the complier did not emit a main function, because it didn’t know the final build product needed to have an executable main function.

Answer (score 0):

Setting Mach-O Type to ‘Executable’ works for me。 [Mach-O](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoM44.png)